# How can partial outputs between nodes be done?

Tags: javascript, hyperhtml

One thing caught my eye reading the features of hyperHTML:

- partial outputs between nodes

I'm trying to render an array of additional elements to the `document.body`, so not removing existing ones that were defined in the html file. A declarative render that would add the array of elements and update the elements if there was a change.

Comment: can you please show an example code to work on? It's hard for me to imagine what you are trying to do exactly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found out how to do it. This is the gist of it.

```
  function update(modals) {
    appendOnce(render(modals));
  }

  function render(modals) {
    return html`${modals.map(renderModal)}`;
  }

  function renderModal(modal) {
    return wire(modal)`
      <div>${modal.id}</div>
      <h2>It is ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    `;
  }
```

It appends each modal once to an existing html file and then if the UI state changes it will update each modal with the changes.

See an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/luwes/xcz3d79f/